# Making a reusable review card component - How to get the star rating

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to be able to make a dynamic card component that will eventialy call an api to get the data. Right now I will be using dummy data.

I want a name, description and star rating for each card. What I am not to sure about is how I would get the star images in each card component.

```
export const ReviewCards: React.FC<ReviewCardsProps> = ({ name, star, description }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Card className="reviewCards sm:h-415">
        <CardContent>
          <div className="flex p-4 justify-between">
            <p className="text-lg">{name}</p>
            <div className="flex w-3.5 space-x-1.5 justify-end">
              <img src={StarIcon} alt="Ratings icon" />
              <img src={StarIcon} alt="Ratings icon" />
              <img src={StarIcon} alt="Ratings icon" />
              <img src={StarIcon} alt="Ratings icon" />
              <img src={EmptyStar} alt="Ratings icon" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <p className="text-sm font-extralight p-7">{description}</p>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
)
}
```

I dont want to manually put in the images. I want to be able to say

```
 <div className="flex w-3.5 space-x-1.5 justify-end">{star}<div>
```

And then when calling the component I want to be able to say:

```
<ReviewCard name="Bianca", star={4} description={...} /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a array and assign the images accordingly..

```
// Array index starts with 0, so added 1 to the index
 const HelperStar = (index) =>
    index + 1 < star ? StarIcon : index + 1 - 0.5 === star ? HalfStar : EmptyStar;
const imageSource = new Array(5)
                        .fill(0)
                        .map((data, index) => HelperStar(index);
    
return (
        // ...
        <div className="flex w-3.5 space-x-1.5 justify-end">
             {imageSource.map((data) => <img src={data} alt="Ratings icon" />}
            </div>
          </div>
        //..
       );
```

Comment: How would I achieve a rating of star={4.5}? If i now say star={4.5} 5 stars are filled instead of 4 and a half. I have an image that is half a filled star, how can I also incorporate that image?

Comment: Updated the code..

Comment: Very interesting solution. I am getting an error saying that value cannot be found?

Comment: oh sorry.. value have to be changed to star as in the name of the props.. updated the code..

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!! I really appreciate the assist!!